# DJANGO_PATH errors and settings issues

Tags: django, settings, sys

I recently upgraded my Ubuntu to 14.04, and consulted this question to solve my erros, [ImportError: No module named _io in ubuntu 14.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23176697/importerror-no-module-named-io-in-ubuntu-14-04). That was solved perfectly.

I also checked out this question as it's similar to mine, [Consistently getting ImportError: Could not import settings 'myapp.settings' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20270297/consistently-getting-importerror-could-not-import-settings-myapp-settings-err), but could not use the same solution.

I do not use manage.py in my project and I have done numerous exports of the PYTHON_PATH to no end of my issues.  Here is my traceback;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/thabang/.virtualenvs/lottostar/bin/django-admin.py", line 5, in <module>
management.execute_from_command_line()
File "/home/thabang/.virtualenvs/lottostar/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/home/thabang/.virtualenvs/lottostar/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/home/thabang/.virtualenvs/lottostar/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
commands = get_commands()
File "/home/thabang/.virtualenvs/lottostar/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 107, in get_commands
apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS
File "/home/thabang/.virtualenvs/lottostar/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 54, in __getattr__
self._setup(name)
File "/home/thabang/.virtualenvs/lottostar/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 49, in _setup
self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
File "/home/thabang/.virtualenvs/lottostar/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 132, in __init__
% (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e)
ImportError: Could not import settings 'lottostar.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named lottostar.settings
```

Comment: without `manage.py' ?

Comment: Yes. And this is a large project that has had almost a year of development into it. So yes, it has been running without.

Comment: I found the problem. The was an issue with the egg files during the virtualenv reinstall.

Though the programs were there, they couldn't be found.I just perfomed another install of the requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem:

The was an issue with the egg files during the virtualenv reinstall. Though the programs were there, they couldn't be found. I just performed another install of the requirements to refresh the egg info.